# Creating a table within a dataset in BigQuery programmatically

Tags: java, api, google-bigquery

Is it possible to create a table within a dataset in BigQuery using the API in Java? I know it's possible with

```
bq mk --schema <fileName> -t <project>:<dataset>.<table>
```

but I can't find a way to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used the Java BigQuery library personally<sup>1</sup>, but it looks like you should call [`BigQuery.create(TableInfo, TableOptions[]`](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.21.1/apidocs/com/google/cloud/bigquery/BigQuery.html#create-com.google.cloud.bigquery.TableInfo-com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery.TableOption...-). That documentation has this example code - assuming you already have an instance of a `BigQuery` interface implementation of course:

```
String datasetName = "my_dataset_name";
String tableName = "my_table_name";
String fieldName = "string_field";
TableId tableId = TableId.of(datasetName, tableName);
// Table field definition
Field field = Field.of(fieldName, Field.Type.string());
// Table schema definition
Schema schema = Schema.of(field);
TableDefinition tableDefinition = StandardTableDefinition.of(schema);
TableInfo tableInfo = TableInfo.newBuilder(tableId, tableDefinition).build();
Table table = bigquery.create(tableInfo);
```

Obviously your schema construction is likely to be a bit more involved for a *real* table, but that should get you started. I can't see any way of loading a schema from a file, but if your schema file is machine-readable in a simple way (e.g. JSON) you could probably write your own parser fairly easily. (And contribute it to the project, should you wish...)

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm the main author of the C# BigQuery library though, so I know what to look for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well I was actually looking for a way to create the table from the schema directly, rather than loading it and iterating through. It's a helpful suggestion, thanks again.

Comment: @EduardoSanchez-Ros: When you say "from the schema directly" you mean from the file? If so, that's a somewhat different question, but I wouldn't expect it to be particularly hard to do. (Personally I've typically just hard-coded the schema in code rather than having it in a separate file, but that's a different matter.)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. As you said I can write my own parser and create the tables out of the schema files. I would be great to have that capability in the API :). Thanks @Jon Skeet

Comment: @EduardoSanchez-Ros: I suggest you file a feature request on the repo: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java

Comment: done https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/2308

Comment: @EduardoSanchez-Ros: Goodo. I'll keep an eye out to see whether we get any demand for it for the .NET library, too :)